# Nuances of meaning between "je me dis", "je trouve", and "je pense"

Tags: synonymes

> Albert ? De nous tous, **je trouve que** c'est celui qui a le moins changé depuis des années.
>
> Albert ? De nous tous, **je me dis que** c'est celui qui a le moins changé depuis des années.
>
> Albert ? De nous tous, **je pense que** c'est celui qui a le moins changé depuis des années.

Do native speakers detect nuances of meaning between the three?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Je **trouve** que' puts the emphasis on the fact that you find that Albert hasn't changed a lot. It doesn't express doubt regarding your opinion.

'Je **me dis** que' is something you say to yourself, which doesn't count as an absolute truth. You're pondering the possibility. It's more like a possible truth.

Lastly, 'je **pense** que' is a very careful way of expressing something you think might be true, but the word emanates incertitude.

Answer (score 3):

Even thought they look really similar and convey pretty much the same message, the timing of their usage makes them just different enough to feel different.

Let's say we take those sentences and make similar ones in English. I dropped the `Albert?`as it kind of forces a prior question or wider context.

---

### Je trouve

Making a point:

> De nous tous, **je trouve** que c'est celui qui a le moins changé depuis des années.
>
> Of all our friends, **I find** he changed the least.

Similar example

> **I find** this site is really useful.
>
> **Je trouve** ce site très utile

---

### Je me dis

Similar to self-thinking as **je me dis** = **I tell myself**

(Skipped as hard to do 1:1 translation)

Similar example

> When I'm scared **I tell myself** that everything will be ok.
>
> Quand j'ai peur **je me dis** que tout ira bien.

---

### Je pense que

Stating an opinion:

> De nous tous, **je pense** que c'est celui qui a le moins changé depuis des années.
>
> Of all our friends, **I believe** he changed the least.

Similar example

> **I believe** this answer is the correct one.
>
> **Je pense** que cette réponse est la bonne.

---

If those seems to be different to you (they do to me at least) then that's pretty much how the french ones sounds to many of us (different).

**They do have enough nuances to sound different**

Comment: I think that these differences are noticeable only for someone studying thouroughly the language and paying attention to the differences. I'm a native and I can't tell any difference between those phrases in an everyday use. I would use them interchangeably.

Comment: @RyanB Some of these expressions can hardly be used interchangeably. From the examples Robijoe gave: *Je me dis que ce site est très utile* is different than *Je trouve que ce site est très utile*. *Quand j'ai peur, je trouve que tout ira bien* is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: Be careful, you wrote *je me di**t*** two times. And I think *je me dis que tout ira bien* is a different *je me dis* than the one meaning *je trouve que*. It's more *je me convaincs que*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps For the _je me dis_ I must admit its a bit hard to come up with a good example. Try saying one aloud and you will notice it won't make sense. Then if you do find one making sense it just doesn't contain words explaining the meaning. Maybe we could consider `je me dis` as removable?